# What are some ways to prove that a k-partite graph is nonplanar?

Tags: graph-theory

I am reading papers on graph theory and I encountered one work that talked about the planarity of a certain graph. In one of the proofs of a theorem, the author stated that the graph $K_{1,2,3}$ is nonplanar. Is this a known result? How can one check that this is planar? And does it hold for other graphs of the form $K_{1,2,n}$?

Comment: What is $K_{1,2,3}$? Can you also reference the paper? I only know that $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ are [non-planar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Kuratowski's_and_Wagner's_theorems).

Comment: I may be wrong, but doesn't $K_{1,2,n}$ include $K_{1,2,3}$ as a subrgaph for $n\ge 3$? Therefore can't be planar if it's true that $K_{1,2,3}$ is not. Also see [wiki/Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler's_formula).

Comment: @Dmitry: It's the complete tripartite graph whose parts have cardinalities $1,2$, and $3$. In effect it's $K_{3,3}$ with two extra edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K_{1,2,3}$ contains a copy of $K_{3,3}$, which is [well known](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) not to be planar.

Comment: So in this particular case, in order to determine if the graph is nonplanar, I need to see if it contains a subgraph that is known to be nonplanar?

Comment: @Brenda: Almost: a subgraph that is a subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.

Comment: Okay, I will read on subdvisions next. Thank you!

Comment: @Brenda: You’re welcome!